# How to replace a line voltage thermostat with a low voltage one?

Tags: thermostat

I have one of those round mechanical knob thermostats (line voltage). I would like to replace it with a wireless thermostat which is controllable from an Android phone. It seems those thermostats are based on 24v voltage.

What are my options to be able to use a wireless thermostat?

Comment: You'll need a transformer, and a relay.